# dts-gen not creating name space issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-definitions

Using dts-gen, i am generating a typescript definition file from JavaScript.

It is converting all the files properly, except namespace issue.

My JavaScript file looks like this....

```
var Utils = Utils || {};


Utils.SimpleDbClient = class SimpleDbClient {
}
```

When i convert i expect the following output (Used the following url to generate this. http://www.typescriptlang.org/play)

```
declare namespace Utils {
    export { SimpleDbClient };
}
declare class SimpleDbClient {
}
```

But i am getting the following one:

```
declare class Utils_SimpleDbClient {
}
```

I am using the following command to generate:

dts-gen --expression-file test.js

My question is, why dts-gen is not creating namespace?

Could you please help me how to do the same?